# How do you construct an array with elements that follow a distribution and sum to 1?

Tags: arrays, math, probability, solver, calculus

I was trying to make a program that produces a list that functions as a probability distribution for another list based on a probability falloff. To do this, I found that the core of the issue lay in the following problem:

Construct a program that outputs a list [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ... , x<sub>n</sub>] such that:

1. The sum of the list is equal to 1.
2. Each item x<sub>n</sub> = px<sub>n-1</sub> where p is some constant that is less than 1.

I was initially attempting to solve a problem where I wanted to construct a probability distribution for the likelihood of selecting indices in an array, this wasn't that hard to do, and I solved it pretty quickly, but then I started wondering about how it would work if I wanted to create a more programmatically dynamic solution, which is when I started distilling the problem and found that it was similar to infinite series, but I couldn't really correlate the two wholly enough to solve it through calculus, because of the fact that it's a finite series, so I tried constructing it with a function whose integral from 0 to n is equal to 1, and that proved difficult. I then tried throwing out the calculus entirely and approaching it from a pure problem solving perspective, and I still couldn't really come up with anything too promising.

This has become more of a curiosity as to how other people will solve it than an actual problem.

Comment: A couple of observations: 1) x2=px1, x3=p\*p\*x1, ... x_i = p^(i-1) \* x1. Therefore 1 = Σx_i = x1 \* (1 + p + p^2 + ... p^(n-1).  2) (p^n - 1) / (p-1) = 1+p+p^2+...p^(n-1).

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any p in (0,1) then you just have to calculate x_1 and you have the whole sequence.

```
1 = x_1 + x_2 + ..... x_n
1 = x_1(1 + p + ..... p^(n-1))
1 = x_1(1 - p^n)/(1 - p)

x_1 = (1 - p)/(1 - p^n)
```

Comment: This actually works for any p as long as 1 - p**n != 0.  However, if you're doing this on a computer it is easy to get an answer that won't exactly sum to 1 when you generate all the values, due to rounding.  If that is an issue, you may need to adjust some of the values by a small epsilon depending on the details of your numeric representation to make it work out.